# Catching and re-using field properties correctly with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I'm going through a feature class and attempting to catch all the fields and their properties, and reuse them in a new output feature class.  Because I'm doing some stuff to the original data in-between, `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management()` doesn't work for me here.

My code:

```
in_fc = <the feature class>
d = arcpy.Describe(in_fc)
in_sr = d.spatialReference
in_fc_name = d.baseName

out_path = "C:/Temp/temp.gdb"
out_fc_name = f"{d.baseName}_edit"

out_fields = []
fields = arcpy.ListFields(in_fc)
for f in fields:
    if f.type == "String":
        field = [f.baseName, f.type, f.aliasName, f.length]
        out_fields.append(field)
    else:
        field = [f.baseName, f.type, f.aliasName, f.precision]
        out_fields.append(field)

# sanity check
for field in out_fields:
    print(field)  # all looks fine

out_fc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(proj_db, out_fc_name, f"{d.shapeType.upper()}", spatial_reference=in_sr)  # works

arcpy.AddFields_management(out_fc, fields)  # doesn't work
```

Fails with a `convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.AddFields_management(*gp_fixargs((in_table, field_description), True)))` and a runtime error.

Since the fields *appear* correct, and since the [ArcPy documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/field.htm) indicates that the Field `type` property is mapped to the `AddFields_management()` `type` parameter, (meaning I should be able to pass in "String" and have it parsed as "TEXT") I'm not sure where this is going wrong.

Comment: Does your code work on a test feature class with one field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can skip the `arcpy.AddFields_management()` step if you simply include the `template` parameter in the `arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management()` step.

Here is my test code, modified:

```
import arcpy
import os

proj_db = r"C:\Temp\project_database.gdb"
in_fc = r"C:\Temp\test_test123.gdb\test"
d = arcpy.Describe(in_fc)
in_sr = d.spatialReference
in_fc_name = d.baseName

out_fc_name = f"{d.baseName}_edit"
    
out_fc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(
        proj_db, 
        out_fc_name, 
        f"{d.shapeType.upper()}", 
        spatial_reference=in_sr, 
        template=in_fc
        )
```

Comment: MUCH better than the duct-tapey way I was going about this, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are are looping through the fields adding to a list called `out_fields` but then you feed in the list `fields` into the AddFields tool...

Look at the Parameters section of the help file for the [AddFields tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/add-fields.htm). What are you adding (or should say had intended to add)? Now look again at the Parameters section of the Field Properties and what does it *actually* want? A [ValueTable](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/valuetable.htm) not a list of lists.

Comment: This is very helpful, I was unaware of the ValueTable object.  Only reason I didn't mark it as the answer is because Keggering pointed out that I was doing it wrong from the beginning, and I should have been simply using feature class 1 as a template for feature class 2.

Comment: @auslander I would not say you were doing it wrong (although you were ;) ), your approach allows you to say change an alias, bump up the field length of text field etc. Keggering's suggestion works if the template is already _exactly_ what you want, which is often the case, but if you need to tweak things then your approach is the way to go.